# Read and Write to AT45DB321 spi flash using at91sam7s64

Tags: c, gcc, spi

I'm using AT45DB321 spi flash with At91sam7s64 but i can not correctly read and write to AT45DB321 , can any one help me to save my next week!
The main problem is that **It seems that nothing have been written so i can not read back anything**
Here is some of the functions i have used to do this:

```
void AT45_MainMemoryProgram(unsigned char buffer, unsigned long address,
                            unsigned char *pointer_ram ,unsigned long n)
{
  AT45_Ready(); //wait until dataflash is ready

  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,(buffer==1)?0x82:0x85); //send opcode

  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,(address>>16)&0xff); //send address
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,(address>>8)&0xff);
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,address&0xff);

  while (n--) //write data
  {
    SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,*(pointer_ram++));
  }
  AT45_Reset();
}
```

---

```
void AT45_ContinousArrayRead(unsigned long address, unsigned char *pointer_ram,
                             unsigned long n)
{
  AT45_Ready(); //wait until dataflash is ready

  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0xE8); //send opcode

  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,(address>>16)&0xff); //send address
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,(address>>8)&0xff);
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,address&0xff);

  //send don't care clocks
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0);
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0);
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0);
  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0);

  while (n--) //read data
  {
    *(pointer_ram++) =  SPI_TXRX(AT91C_BASE_SPI ,0);;
  }
  AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SPIEN | AT91C_SPI_LASTXFER;
  AT45_Reset();

}
```

---

```
unsigned char SPI_TXRX(AT91S_SPI *spi , unsigned char data)
{
  unsigned char temp;
  spi->SPI_TDR = data; // send data
  while(!(spi->SPI_SR & 1));
  temp = spi->SPI_RDR & 0xff;
  return temp;
}
```

---

```
void spi_config()
{
    AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_ASR = (AT91C_PA12_MISO | AT91C_PA13_MOSI | AT91C_PA11_NPCS0 | AT91C_PA14_SPCK);
    AT91C_BASE_PIOA->PIO_PDR = (AT91C_PA12_MISO | AT91C_PA13_MOSI | AT91C_PA11_NPCS0 | AT91C_PA14_SPCK);    // Set in Periph mode
    AT91C_BASE_PMC->PMC_PCER = (unsigned int) 1 << AT91C_ID_SPI;
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SWRST;
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SWRST;
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CR = AT91C_SPI_SPIEN;
    wait();
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_MR = (AT91C_SPI_MSTR | AT91C_SPI_PS | T91C_SPI_MODFDIS);
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CSR[0] = AT45_CSR(mck, spck);
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CSR[1] = AT45_CSR(mck, spck);
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CSR[2] = AT45_CSR(mck, spck);
    AT91C_BASE_SPI->SPI_CSR[3] = AT45_CSR(mck, spck);
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working "correctly"? Does this mean you *can* read and write, but it does not write the correct information? Maybe it does, and it only does not *read* correct - or the other way around.

Comment: We cannot really trouble shoot stuff like this.   It needs the hardware and meter/scope  to see what is happening on the lines.  For all we know, there is no power on the chip:(

Comment: @Jongware is that the reason of down vote? **:)** the answer is NO. It seems that nothing have been written so i can not read back anything

Comment: @MartinJames i just want to get help if you see anything wrong in my codes, or if you are having any idea that i can try

Comment: Thank you for not assuming it was me downvoting. I was merely inquiring why you can state it does not work "correctly". There **must** be something that made you look at this code and think "this does not work". (Oops: you did. Sorry. [edit] that into your post.) Maybe it's your Read that does not work .

Comment: @Jongware thanks bro, i will edit my post. just this problem seems to make me crazy these days :)

Comment: Verify with another chip your Read code is correct. That will halve the debugging. If your code comes from another source, check it for specifications, caveats, and updates. As @MartinJames says, it could be that one chip that's malfunctioning.

Comment: I am interested in how you implemented this! Please come back at me so we can get into contact